# Parametric equations - finding A

Tags: parametric

The curve with parametric equations **x = a(t-2), y = at² + 2 (where a≠0)**, meets the y-axis at the point **(0,5)**.

(a) Find the value of the constant a.

(b) Hence determine whether the curve meets the x-axis

Comment: For part (a), put x=0, get value of t, and substitute it in y

Comment: @shailesh wait can you work out t?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a) we have
\begin{align}
\big(\,x,\,y\,\big)=\big(\,0,\,5\,\big)\implies
\begin{cases} a\,t-2\,a=0 \\ a\,t^2+2 = 5 \end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases} a\,t =2\,a \\ a\,t^2  = 3 \end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases} t =2 \\ a  = \dfrac{3}{4} \end{cases}
\end{align}
For part (b) observe that 
$$ y = \dfrac{3}{4}\,t^2+2 \implies  \forall \; t \in \mathbb R \quad y\left(t\right)\ge 2$$
Therefore curve never reaches $\,x\,$ axis.